# ask before exit from windows form in c#

Tags: c#, sql

```
 private void Inward_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
         DialogResult dilog = MessageBox.Show("Do you really want to exit", "Exit", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        if (dilog == DialogResult.Yes)
        {

            con.Open();
            try
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("truncate table Inward_data1", con);
                    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    MessageBox.Show("Data Clear Successfully......");
                    sum = 0;

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    ex = null;
                }
                con.Close();
                this.Close();
        }
            else if (dilog == DialogResult.No)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
            }


    }
```

this is my code i want one message box before closing this form,if user i click on yes on dilog box result window one SQL query should execute that is truncate table,this is not my main form,this form is child form,so when i click on yes on dilog box the dilog box constantly asking "do u want to exit",whats wrong in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is with `this.Close();`, remove the line and see the form getting closed. `this.Close();` will trigger the closing event again and that results in `dialog box constantly asking "do u want to exit"`